# Books on infinite sets

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, cardinals, infinity, large-cardinals

I'm a senior undergraduate Pure Math student. I'm looking for books/ problems about large/infinite cardinals and infinite sets. Unsolved or challenging problems are very much welcome.

It shouldn't be anything to technical but I usually like books with lots of demonstrations and nothing too constructive.

To give you some background on what I've studied, I have learnt the ZFC axioms, some theory about Von Neumann ordinals, cardinal arithmetic, the aleph numbers, the continuum hypothesis, etc... I had two Algebra Courses last year and I'm taking Set theory now.
Can anyone recommend me good references on this? I want to star working on this subject to later develop a theme to research.

Thank you

Comment: Your question is well intentioned, but referring to https://math.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask it would appear you are off-topic for this site.

Comment: @Maria try sending emails to some professor about the topic that you want to study, maybe someone give some references

Comment: I once wrote something which might help you get some recommendations, https://karagila.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/ests-wh.pdf

Comment: Thank you so much! I’m going to check the refences in the article.

Comment: Try P. Komjath & V. Totik, Problems and theorems in classical set theory https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387302935

Comment: I also suggest Komjath & Totik, nothing else comes even close to it.